# Does python have a non-lazy version of itertools.groupby?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I don't need the laziness of itertools.groupby. I just want to group my list into a dict of lists as such:

```
dict([(a, list(b)) for a,b in itertools.groupby(mylist, mykeyfunc)])
```

Is there a standard function that already does this?

Comment: Does the laziness hurt in any way?

Comment: In principle, a non-lazy version might be more efficient - it gets the whole groupby done in one go, avoiding laziness overheads and using the cache well. Even so, I'd be surprised if it's causing you any real issues. My advice, stolen from the old song - "don't worry be happy".

Comment: It's a pain to test lazy code in the repl.

Comment: If you wrap lazy functions in a list() or dict(), then the code loop should be small enough to not cause any large overhead. Thus the ability to fit all inside any instruction cache(s) should not be hampered too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's not a function included in the standard library to do this.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have a one-line function already that does what you want.  Use it.

Comment: My question is not "how do I do this?" I am seeking to avoid reimplementing a standard function.